# Why am I getting the extra xmlns="" using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, linq-to-xml

I'm using LINQ to XML to generate a piece of XML. Everything works great except I'm throwing in some empty namespace declarations somehow. Does anyone out there know what I'm doing incorrectly? Here is my code

```
    private string SerializeInventory(IEnumerable<InventoryInformation> inventory)
    {
        var zones = inventory.Select(c => new {
            c.ZoneId
            , c.ZoneName
            , c.Direction
        }).Distinct();

        XNamespace ns = "http://www.dummy-tmdd-address";
        XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

        var xml = new XElement(ns + "InventoryList"
                               , new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi)
                               , zones.Select(station => new XElement("StationInventory"
                               , new XElement("station-id", station.ZoneId)
                               , new XElement("station-name", station.ZoneName)
                               , new XElement("station-travel-direction", station.Direction)
                               , new XElement("detector-list"
                               , inventory.Where(p => p.ZoneId == station.ZoneId).Select(plaza =>
                               new XElement("detector", new XElement("detector-id", plaza.PlazaId)))))));

        xml.Save(@"c:\tmpXml\myXmlDoc.xml");
        return xml.ToString();
    }
```

And here is the resulting xml. I hope it renders correctly? The browser may hide the tags.

```
<InventoryList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.dummy-tmdd-address">
<StationInventory xmlns="">
  <station-id>999</station-id> 
  <station-name>Zone 999-SEB</station-name> 
  <station-travel-direction>SEB</station-travel-direction> 
 <detector-list>
<detector>
  <detector-id>7503</detector-id> 
 </detector>
<detector>
  <detector-id>2705</detector-id> 
 </detector>
</detector-list>
</StationInventory>
</InventoryList>
```

Notice the empty namespace declaration in the first child element. Any ideas how I can remedy this? Any tips are of course appreciated.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the missing namespace in:

```
new XElement("StationInventory"...
```

This implicitly indicates the empty namespace "" for the StationInvetory element. You should do:

```
new XElement(ns + "StationInventory"...
```

Note that you must do this for any element you create that lives in the `ns` namespace. The XML serializer will make sure to qualify elements with the correct namespace prefix according to scope.

Answer (score 0):

Want to add to Peter Lillevold's answer.

XML Attributes don't require namespase in their XName

In addition to casting string to Xname:
The **{myNamespaseName}** will be casted to **XNamespase** on casting of **"{myNamespaseName}nodeName"** to **XName**

Also, look to the code structure that simplifies reading of the constructor method:

```
private readonly XNamespace _defaultNamespace = "yourNamespace";

public XElement GetXmlNode()
{
    return
    new XElement(_defaultNamespace + "nodeName", 
        new XElement(_defaultNamespace + "nodeWithAttributes", 
            new XAttribute("attribute1Name", "valueOfAttribute1"),
            new XAttribute("attribute2Name", "valueOfAttribute2"),
            "valueOfnodeWithAttributes"
        )
    );
}
```

or

```
public XElement GetXmlNode()
{
    return
    new XElement("{myNamespaseName}nodeName", 
        new XElement("{myNamespaseName}nodeWithAttributes", 
            new XAttribute("attribute1Name", "valueOfAttribute1"),
            new XAttribute("attribute2Name", "valueOfAttribute2"),
            "valueOfnodeWithAttributes"
        )
    );
}
```